How can I share color swatches on a Word template, so that my client will be able to easily use their brand colors?
We are working with Word 16.9 on a Mac.
We have a simple document template for our client to use / re-purpose in Word.
How can I set up colours within the document so that when I send the document template to my client, their team will be able to see any color swatches / themes that have been set up?
Currently if I add custom color swatches in Design/Colors – and then save / send the Word file, my client does not see the custom colours I set up.
detail of where my custom colors appear at the moment...

I believe those swatches exist in the Template, not in the document. Have you tried setting up a custom template to see whether that information carries over? Also, for graphic design, I'd suggest that Word may not be the best tool for conveying branded color designs, for the reason you've given. Generally, converting to a less mutable format such as PDF, or using a graphic design-focused tool like Publisher.

We have tried setting these in the template. The colours dont seem to be reliably available on th client side, assuming the user just opens the word doc, rather then importing a theme file.
I have a solution that does seem to work — setting a paragraph style for each colour!
I know this is a bodge job, but needs must. Obviously I'd rather be working in Indesign, but that's not possible here, we are simply making a basic template for wider company use :)
